# How can summon a stationary mob?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to try and keep a mob stationary without any walls in Bedrock Edition. How do I do that?

> Way to do it in Java Edition: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-the-summon-command-to-create-an-AI-less-invincible-mob-in-Minecraft

Comment: What's the link for?

Comment: @Wrigglenite It shows how it is done in Java. It could give references on how to do it in Bedrock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no NBT tags on Minecraft Bedrock, but two of those three are possible to do with commands. While you can't remove a mob's AI, you can keep it in one location by placing an always active repeating command block with the command `tp @e[type=<entity_name>] <x> <y> <z>`. For example, `tp @e[type=zombie] 0 4 0` which on a superflat world would keep the zombie in place at 0, 0.

To make an entity invulnerable, you need to use `/effect`. For the zombie, use `effect @e[type=zombie] resistance 1000000 255 true`. This will apply Resistance 255 to the zombie for 1000000 seconds without particles.

I am unaware of a way to make any entity silent through commands, unfortunately, but at least those two are able to be done.

Comment: Now I can have my punching bag.